# Does gtest/gmock have a way to stub every instance of a class?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

Is it possible to stub every instance of a class in C++ using GTest/GMock like RSpec has with [any_instance](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)? Read the docs but couldn't find anything on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. There is no such built-in functionality in **gtest/gmock**.

Long answer: There is no way to impose certain behavior on an arbitrary C++ class, especially those in C++ standard library (C++ equivalent of Ruby core library). These are two fundamentally different languages. Ruby is a "message oriented" language, all objects respond to messages. Such concept does not exist in C++, so there is not way to achieve the behavior you desire.